# Searching through nodes and outputting the details on gmap

Tags: location, google-maps

I have a gmap that is displaying all the information of real estate listings that I put in.

Now I want a text search that basically searches through the nodes and outputs the information in the same map and filter it basically.

So if I search for 2 bedroom in Boston in a simple text search. (Hopefully the search will have auto complete)

It will only show me the two bedrooms in boston I selected. (Boston is a node type) not part of gmap.

Basically I need a text search to filter the map listings which I dropped on it.

I don't want spatial searching.

Help!

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to be a search box? If not, use GMAP's Views integration and create exposed filters for the fields you want to filter by. Instead of a search box, use a dropdown for bedrooms, city, and whatever other filterable fields you include.

Using a text input/search box may cause usability issues. You can't account for the variety of keywords a user may input, nor will you be able to filter appropriately for unknown terms. Giving the user defined filters (which they are familiar with) will be much easier for them to understand and use.

Better Exposed Filters may come in handy here depending on what type of filters you use -> http://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters

Comment: The argument you are making now is the exact same one I made. The client wants it to be a text search box. When I suggests the issue of usability to them they suggested autocomplete and correction similar to what google does. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you really need to go the google search auto-complete approach, you'd probably have to setup Solr Search, which will cost significantly more than the exposed filter Views approach. Integrating Solr Search with GMAP is likely a big undertaking as well.  If I were you, I'd explain to the client that it will cost them way more money to go the google-style approach. Hopefully they'd shy away once they see the price tag.

http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr
http://groups.drupal.org/node/58623